# Git master and development out of sync

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I have a master and development branch.  The main (server) repos are hosted in Azure Devops (on premise). I did two Pull Requests (from feature branches into development) for changes in my development branch.

> PR1: feature-branch-1 -> development
>
> PR2: feature-branch-2 -> development

Then I thought, I need to sync my development branch with my master branch, so I did a Pull Request  from my development branch to my master branch, accepted, committed.

> PR3: development -> master

Now it is saying my development branch is "1 behind and 2 ahead of master"

Comparing development to master shows my two feature Pull Requests.
Comparing master to development shows my merge PR to sync the branches.

What in my process did I do wrong, and how do I fix this - get them in sync?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The process you did is correct, but depending on what you chose one of the following happened.

- When you performed the PR merge, you chose "Merge", which will create a merge commit on the target (master) branch. Thus Master is 1 ahead of development.
- When you performed the PR merge, you chose "Squash", in which case it will create a new commit with the changes to target (master) branch. This Master is 1 commit ahead of development and 2 commits behind.
- When you performed a Fast Forward, if no merge were required, the target and source branch would now be the same. And no merge commit would be added.
- When you had rebased develop onto master, all changes would be replayed on the master branch and then committed. You'd have to force push develop in that case.

To make sure develop is back in sync with master, you have a few options:

- Merge master back to develop. Develop will be 1 merge commit ahead of master afterwards.
- Rebase develop onto master and force push. Develop will be the same as master + any outstanding changes will be replayed on top of develop.
- Reset develop to master and force push. Develop will be the same as master + any outstanding changes will be lost.
- Delete/rename the current develop branch and create a new one from master.

Comment: Azure DevOps allows applying branch policies, and both master and development have a branch policy to "Enforce a Merge Strategy" of Squash Merge.

Comment: Having squash merge on two related branches will cause issues like these.

Comment: @jesshouwing do you have a better setup I could use? I'm all ears, trying to get this standardized

Comment: I tend to do most squashing locally or on my feature branch before merging to develop. That way the need for squash-merge on the pull request is a lot less. You can then just do a normal merge from master to develop. Due to the way Git works, you'll usually end up that master is 1-commit-ahead (the merge commit), unless you do a fast-forward-merge. This is to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

> Now it is saying my development branch is "1 behind and 2 ahead of
>   master"
>
> Comparing development to master shows my two feature Pull Requests.
>   Comparing master to development shows my merge PR to sync the
>   branches.

No error about your operation, and the answer(`1 behind and 2 ahead of master`) is also correct.

Before all, you need to know what does "[Squash Merge](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/squash-a-whole-new-way-to-merge-pull-requests/)" mean.

Let's name these commits: merge commit from **feature-branch-1** to **Development** is **A**. The commit from **feature-branch-2** to **Development** is **B**. The merge commit created from **Development** to **Master** is **C**.

While performing merge **feature-branch-1** to Development with `Squash Merge`, it will create new commit **A'**. In fact, compare with their content, there's no defference between A and A'. But the feature branch itself does not have a commit merging it into the default branch. 
[image]

So, follow this logic. While you performing merge Development to Master, it will create one new commit **C'**. After merge, in Master branch, it just add one new commit **C'**, not **C**. That's why you get the behind|ahead as `1 behind and 2 ahead of master`.

Change your compare branch to **Development**, you will see that the **behind|ahead** of your **feature-branch-1** and **feature-branch-2** is **2|1**. That's all because of **Squash Merge**.

The advantage of Squash Merge is keeping your default branch histories clean and easy to follow without demanding any workflow changes on your team.

But if you want get them in sync with history, please change your merge type as **Basic Merge**.

Comment: I would like to protect my master branch so that hot fixes need to be done through a pull request, which i would then merge down to development, but I'd like dev and master in sync. maybe the PR merge policy is unnecessary and PRs just need to be a business practice. or I need to turn it off when merging dev to master

Comment: Got that. If choose **Basic Merge**, you can still set branch policy to protect the master or other branches. Just need to choose **Basic Merge** while you complete the pr.

Comment: with branch policy set to Merge Strategy Squash Merge, when I complete the PR "Squash changes when merging" is checked and disabled (I can't change). Or maybe you are saying to perform this merge somehow outside of a PR?

Comment: No, if you want to use Basic Merge while you complete the pr, you must modify your branch policy, change Limit merge types and make Basic merge (no fast-forward) selected. In another way, if you can change the permission setting, you can go Project Setting->Repositories->(project name)->master branch->set **Bypass policies when completing pull requests** as Allow(this can bypass the limitation of branch policy).

Comment: Not working for me sorry. I set security to override both branches. merged dev -> master, override, unchecked squash. master was then 2 ahead of dev.then merged master to dev, same settings, dev is now 1 ahead of master.

Comment: It's normal for me to show "2 behind and 0 ahead". Did you set the bypass to allow? Did you choose basic merge after you complete pr? For me, I first check my group, and set the permission of my group as allow. And then create pr to merge Dev to Master->complete pr->basic merge->override.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194608/discussion-between-user210757-and-merlin-liang-msft).